# pull access denied for Amazon ECR, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

1. I have an image in an Amazon ECR Repository called workshop
2. I have a Dockerfile to pull that image
3. CodeBuild should build the new image from Dockerfile

Problem:

> pull access denied for xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/workshop, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

In my buildspec file, I've tried to login with docker, but nothing changes.

```
 phases:
  pre_build:
  commands:
   - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
   - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
   - aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 
     xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
   - CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION="${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION:-$IMAGE_TAG}"
   - IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
```

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/workshop:latest

CMD ["echo", "Hallo!"]

RUN code-server
```

What may cause the Problem?

Comment: What is the role on your CB project? Does it have permissions to use ECR?

Comment: What do you mean by CB? I gave my ECR Repository the policy like `Allow: ecr:*`, so I can pull the images from ECR but it didn't work. @Marcin

Comment: CB - codebuild. You CB needs permissions to access ECR. Have you set it role for that?

Comment: @Marcin I think I haven't, I will give it a try

Comment: Encountered this issue today and resolved it by: 1) adding permission policy in ECR registry to allow `ecr:*` for Principal AWS account id and then 2) adding service role to CodeBuild to allow `ecr:*` for `resources: *` and 3) added `aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/image:tag` to the `install` phase of my `buildspec.yml` file

Answer (score 7):

Try to update your aws-cli and use latest version, because `get-login` is deprecated.

New command is like this:

```
aws ecr get-login-password \
    --region <region> \
| docker login \
    --username AWS \
    --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

## References:

- get-login-password: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html
- get-login: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately th problem remains. I also tried to give my account a policy like: `{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:repository/workshop"
        }
    ]
}` But it did not work either..

Answer (score 0):

@vasil001

Like describe here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policies.html

You have to specify **the complete arn** (with region code and account id) of your ECR repository or repositorues if you set IAM policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple account configured on your console try this. This works for me:

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region <your_region> --profile <yourprofile> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <Account_ID>.dkr.ecr.<your_region>.amazonaws.com

$ docker pull <Image_URI>
```